# can my control have multiple themes by default

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a control and i put its template in generic.xaml.

is it possible to have other themes like:
bluesky.xaml
tealocean.xaml

How would I do this?  How would the themes get changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best currently available way is to use `Theme` control from a silverlight control toolkit to dynamically change themes.

Here is an article on this: http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx